# Setting softtabstop for Python

Tags: softtabstop

I am following [this guide from realpython.com](https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/) to fine tune vim for Python development. It suggests the following section in the `.vimrc` file:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
```

This produces the following error when I open a Python file:

```
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Auto commands for "*.py":
E518: Unknown option: set 
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

As it turns out, the error goes away if the `softtabstop` instruction is commented out. How should it be set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslash is a line-continuation in Vim script. Hence your code is interpreted as `set tabstop=4 set softtabstop=4 ...` and so on. And, obviously, it's a syntax error. Your options are:

1. Merge options into a single "set" command:

   ```
   set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 ...
   ```
2. Use "bar" to mark command's end:

   ```
   set tabstop=4 | set softtabstop=4 | set shiftwidth=4 | ...
   ```
3. Split into several autocommands:

   ```
   au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4
   au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set softtabstop=4
   au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set shiftwidth=4
   ...
   ```

However, in this case it's even better to create a dedicated script for standard "ftplugin" to process. The file name should be `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` (or `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python.vim` under Windows). The content is simply a number of "set" commands. You don't have to trap an autocommand yourself as the plugin will do this for you. You have only to enable the plugin with `filetype plugin on` which is probably switched on anyway.

Comment: The pipes also produces an error: `E749: empty buffer`, but the other two solutions are functional.